# How to access Text decomposition functions in Protolude

Tags: haskell

## TL;DR:

In the standard prelude it is possible to operate on text (`String`s) with functions such as `head`, `take` etc. `Protolude` replaces these components with better ones, but this seems to come at a cost of losing the ability to apply many of the Prelude's functions to its standard text type.

## A simple problem

I need to find out whether some word starts with an uppercase character.

## Warming up

```
import Data.Char

startsWithUppercase :: String -> Bool
startsWithUppercase = isUpper . head
```

this works ...

```
λ startsWithUppercase "Yes"
True
λ startsWithUppercase "no"
False
```

except that `head` is a partial function

```
λ startsWithUppercase ""
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

## A safer version

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead []    = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x

startsWithUppercase :: String -> Bool
startsWithUppercase = (maybe False isUpper) . safeHead
```

This seems to fix the problem:

```
λ map startsWithUppercase $ words "Yes no"
[True,False]
λ startsWithUppercase ""
False
```

except that I want to use `Text` rather than `String`

## Moving from `String` to `Text`

Let's try a direct translation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Prelude hiding (head)
import Data.Text
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

safeHead :: Text -> Maybe Char
safeHead "" = Nothing
safeHead t  = Just . head $ t

startsWithUppercase :: Text -> Bool
startsWithUppercase = (maybe False isUpper) . safeHead
```

It seems to work ...

```
yes, no, crash :: Text
yes   = "Yes"
no    = "no"
crash = ""

λ Prelude.map startsWithUppercase [yes, no, crash]
[True,False,False]
```

... but I can't help wondering why Hoogle didn't come up with anything
interesting in response to `Text -> Maybe Char`.

Anyway, I'm sick and tired of these partial functions all over the
place: I don't want these gaping holes in my static guarantees. I
know, let's use one of these modern Prelude replacemens. `Protolude`
looks good, and seems to have many proponents.

## Moving to Protolude

Protolude, among its many virtues, is supposed to address the two main
issues I have addressed above:

- Eradicate `String`, make `Text` available by default.
- Eradicate partial functions, make safe ones available by default.

It even imports `Data.Maybe` for me.

Sounds great. Let's do it!

There will be no need to write `safeHead`, because in `Protolude`
`head` already is safe, and generic to boot:

```
λ :t head
head :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe a
```

Excellent!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import Protolude
import Data.Char

startsWithUppercase :: Text -> Bool
startsWithUppercase = (maybe False isUpper) . head
```

Oh dear:

```
 Lib.hs     8  23 error           [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
     • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘f0 Char’
       Expected type: Text -> Bool
         Actual type: f0 Char -> Bool
     • In the expression: (maybe False isUpper) . head
       In an equation for ‘startsWithUppercase’:
           startsWithUppercase = (maybe False isUpper) . head (intero)
```

`Protolude.head` is defined on `Foldable`s, which `Text` isn't.

I guess I'll have to write my own `safeHead` for `Text` after all.

Hmm, but for that I used `Text.head` and `Protolude` hides that away.

After numerous further failed attempts to get this to work, I have to stand back and think: I'm trying to find whether the
first character of a piece of `Text` is uppercase, in a modern
Prelude.

What am I missing? What is the sane solution to this simple problem? More generally, how does one break up `Text` into sub-text *within* `Protolude`?

## Edit: Clarification

The benefits I would like to reap from `Protolude` include

- reduction of boilerplate imports
- reduction of boilerplate depencency specification

`Protolude` has `text` as a depnedency and it imports `Text` components.

I am looking for a way of achieving whis *without* having to explicitly specify imports and dependencies beyond the ones perfomed implicitly by `Protolude`.

Specifically, the `head`, `take`, `any` etc. that are exported by `Protolude` are defined on `[]` and `Foldable`, and do not work with `Text`. Any attempt to import anything from `Data.Text` explicitly (undesirable boilerplate number 1) fails because it's a "member of a hidden package `text`". To get around this one would have to explicitly specify `text` as a dependency (undersirable boilerplate number 2).

Is there a way to get this to work without explicit imports and/or dependencies?

Comment: Replacing your protolude dependency with text (and your Protolude import with Data.Text) preserves the amount of boilerplate and achieves the stated goal... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about `any isUpper . take 1` (with the appropriate `Data.Text` variants of `any` and `take`)?

Comment: Yes, I've been barking up that tree, but getting my hands on the appropriate variants in `Protolude` is proving to be more difficult than I would like.

Comment: @jacg Why is it difficult? `import qualified Data.Text as T` and you're on your way.

Comment: Because I'm using the `protolude` package to pull in dependencies (such as `text`), and when I did exactly what you suggested, the compiler replied with `Could not load module ‘Data.Text’ It is a member of the hidden package ‘text-1.2.3.1’.`

Comment: @duplode That's the point: I don't *want* to import `Data.Text` or specify `text` as a dependency explicitly! If that's the *only* way to get it to work, then so be it, but I was hoping that I would be able to write this trivial function on `Text` without going outside what `Protolude` provides. Is that really an unrealistic expectation?

Comment: @jacg Yes, it is unrealistic to expect any prelude replacement to provide every library function you will need. We have non-prelude libraries on Hackage for a very good reason.

Comment: The standard Prelude provides a type for storing text (`String`) and `head`, `any`, `take`, etc. that work with it, making the required function easy to write within that Prelude. `Protolude` provides a type for storing text (`Text`) and `head`, `any`, `take`, etc. which, in spite of being more polymorphic than those in the standard Prelude, do **not** work with this Prelude's basic text type, making the required function (apparently?) impossible to write with this Prelude. Whatever other merits `Protolude` has, in this respect it's a step backwards. Something valuable seems to have been lost.

Comment: To import Data.Text (or otherwise directly use the text package alongside protolude, as opposed to using just the parts of text exposed by protolude modules) it is necessary to add it to the build dependencies of your project. (This is the comment I had written above and that jacg replied to, stripped of a wrong sentence I had accidentally left in it.)

Answer (score 0):

Protolude exports an unpack function which allows you to once again work with Strings:

```
% ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude -XOverloadedStrings
GHCi, version 8.4.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> import Data.Char
Data.Char> import Protolude
Data.Char Protolude> any isUpper . take 1 . strConv Strict $ ("Yes" :: Text)
True
```

Comment: ...but in my own developments (and I suspect you feel similarly) I would greatly prefer using the `Text` API directly. Converting to `String` sort of defeats the benefits of using the better data type in the first place.

Comment: Yes, certainly I'd rather incur the dependency on text and actually operate on the value as Text.

Comment: Agreed, the extra boilerplate is preferable to dropping down to `String`.